# PrintWriter won't write in UTF-8

Tags: java, printwriter

My code is

```
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true);
output.print(SomeString);
```

but if i run this I Still have Problems wit ßÄÖÜ and so on.
is there someone how can explain me this?

If i do

```
System.out.print(someString);
```

it prints out perfect with äöüß
thanks for helping

Comment: Thanks @user1902288, it does encode properly only exceldosen't seem to bother the encoding. As I opend it with Notepad++ it's perfect. I don't need to view the file in this stage it's only a substage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
res.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                         new OutputStreamWriter(res.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"), true);
```

also you can check encoding type

```
String encoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
            if ((encoding != null) && (encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("utf-8")))
            {
                response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
            }
```

Comment: Also make sure that whatever editor you are using to see "your" file that it supports UTF-8 and uses it to display the information. (I had similar issues until i noticed i acctually already have UTF-8 but my Tool used another encoding to display my information)